# How to evaluate a relative XPath inside another XPath in Puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, xpath, puppeteer

Here is my code where I have got the element Handle of some target divs

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");


(async () => {
const searchString = `https://www.google.com/maps/search/restaurants/@-6.4775265,112.057849,3.67z`;


const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto(searchString);

const xpath_expression ='//div[contains(@aria-label, "Results for")]/div/div[./a]';

await page.waitForXPath(xpath_expression);
const targetDivs = await page.$x(xpath_expression);

// const link_urls = await page.evaluate((...targetDivs) => {
//   return targetDivs.map((e) => {
//     return e.textContent;
//   });
// }, ...targetDivs);

})();
```

I have two relative XPath links inside these target Divs which contain related data

```
'link' : './a/@href'
'title': './a/@aria-label'
```

I have a sample of similar python code like this

```
from parsel import Selector

response = Selector(page_content)

results = []

for el in response.xpath('//div[contains(@aria-label, "Results for")]/div/div[./a]'):
    results.append({
        'link': el.xpath('./a/@href').extract_first(''),
        'title': el.xpath('./a/@aria-label').extract_first('')
    })
```

How to do it in **puppeteer**?

Comment: An element handle also has a method `$x` so process your targetDivs and call e.g. `await targetDiv.$x('a/@href')` on each of them.

Comment: @Martin Honnen tried elementHandle but got undefined values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can get the `href` and `ariaLabel` property values with e.g.

```
   const targetDivs = await page.$x(xpath_expression);

   targetDivs.forEach(async (div, pos) => { 
     const links = await div.$x('a[@href]'); 
     const href = await (await links[0].getProperty('href')).jsonValue();
     const ariaLabel = await (await links[0].getProperty('ariaLabel')).jsonValue(); 
     console.log(pos, href, ariaLabel);
   });
```

These are the element properties, not the attribute values, which, in the case of `href`, might for instance mean you get an absolute instead of a relative URL but I haven't checked for that particular page whether it makes a difference. I am not sure the `$x` allows direct attribute node or even string value selection, the documentation only talks about element handles.